# trouble browsing and selecting a file IE / VBA

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, file-upload

I am having problems this.

I have a page where I need to upload files. When I click on 'Browser' the 'Choose a file to upload' window opens and I need to select (double click) there a TXT file.

I tried using Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) but this object is not recognized.

Any help will be appreciated!

```
    Sub Main
    ' Get the browser object belonging to the active/topmost IE tab
    Dim objIe
    Dim activeDocument
    Dim Button
    Set activeDocument = Nothing


    ' Try and get the window object of the active IE tab
    Set objIe = GetActiveBrowserObj 'this is a function previously defined that allows me to work on the active browser window
        If objIe Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "Could not get active IE document object”
          Exit Sub
        End If

    ' Assign the document object to the activeDocument variable
    Set activeDocument = objIe.Document
        If activeDocument Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "Could not get active IE document object"
          Exit Sub
        End If
    'Click the browse button to upload the first TXT file
    Set Button = objIe.Document.getElementById("txtfile1")
        Button.Click

    chooseFile()

End Sub

Private Sub chooseFile()

    Dim fd
    Dim strTxt As String

    Start:
    'Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    With fd
       .Title = "Choose File to Upload" 'Change the title to suit
       .Filters.Add "txt files", "*.txt", 1 'Change the filters to suit, or omit for none
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       If .Show = -1 Then
           'The user made a selection.  The variable strWorkBook will contain the path\name of the file
           strTxt = .SelectedItems(1)
       Else
           response = MsgBox("You have not selected a txt file")
           If response = vbRetry Then
               GoTo Start
           Else
               Exit Sub
           End If
       End If
    End With
    Set fd = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use API's to interact with that window by finding the window which has the name "**Choose File To Upload**"

Here is an example

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret

    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose File To Upload")

    If Ret <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "File upload window Found"
    Else
        MsgBox "File upload window Not Found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Once you have locked on to the releavnt window then you have to find the `Handle` of the `Textbox` and then paste your filename with full path there. Once that is done, you find the handle of the `Open` Button and finally click it.

I have covered it extensively [here](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2012/02/02/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window-part-ii/). Though in the example that I have posted in the link, I am saving the file using `Save As` but you have to use the same approach to find the handle and upload the file.

HTH

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried your code and the function does not recognize the window 'Choose File to Upload'. It always shows "File upload window Not Found". Do you know what can be causing this? I open this window before running the code. Thanks.